# Not able to match colon using grep regexp

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a large ASCII file.  Each line contains a field like:

```
"id":"N119PM-1442267121-144-0"
```

The double quotes are actually in the file, not my addition.  The fields are delimited by commas but they do not necessarily appear in the same order from line to line, which means that using cut is not a viable option.

I have been using:

```
grep -o '"id":"[A-Aa-z0-9-]\+' <filename>
```

and it works for the type of field shown above.  But, there is a problem.  A large number of these fields look like

```
"id":"JBU19-1442091600-schedule-0000:4"
```

In other words, they have an extra colon and number at the end.  I have not been able to select fields with these extra characters.

I've tried:

```
grep -o '"id":"[A-Aa-z0-9:-]\+' <filename>  
grep -o '"id":"[A-Aa-z0-9\:-]\+' <filename>  
grep -o '"id":"[A-Aa-z0-9-]\+\(:[0-9]\+\)' <filename>
```

without success.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have also tried changing the : to % first then search on %, but this didn't work, either.

Comment: Crap, stupid mistake.  Thanks.  I really hate regular expressions, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `GNU GREP`, you can use `-P` in grep command

```
grep -oP '"id":"[A-Za-z0-9-:]+"' <filename>
"id":"N119PM-1442267121-144-0"
"id":"JBU19-1442091600-schedule-0000:4"
```

> -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression

Comment: This answer is only usable if you are using GNU grep. I see no platform or grep flavour specified in the question.

Comment: There is nothing Perl-specific in your solution.  In fact, you could use it with `grep -E` just as well.  But there is also nothing in the OP's attempt which particularly requires or dictates anything more than Basic RE, i.e. plain old `grep` (though the backslashes required on `\+` etc are a nuisance).